# File layout for file

Tags: text-processing, command-line, hp-ux

I have a file with numbers in like this:

```
1234
5678
3456
```

How can I get this on one line using a bash shell script with a space between each like this

```
1234 5678 3456
```

Comment: Do you know it's going to be three lines in your file, or may there be a thousand or more lines?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use `xargs`.   e.g.

```
xargs < file.txt
```

Comment: Brilliant - thank you..

Comment: well, it'll only work if all the numbers will fit into one shell command line.  I don't know what the line length limit is on hp-ux, but on linux it's about 2 million characters.   If there's more than will fit in one line, xargs will print a second (or third...) line.

Comment: Daft question - the max there will be is 8 sets of numbers. I then want to read the file.txt and make that into a variable called numbers so that when numbers is called it contains 1234 5678 3456.  I know there will be some quoting cus of spaces but unsure how to do it.

Comment: `numbers="$(xargs < file.txt)"`

Comment: awesome, worked a treat, many thanks..

Comment: I'm also trying work out a way that when I read a users input for the numbers that I don't output letters, a number below 1000 or over 9999 to the file im using. I have this but I don't think its right.

Comment: # Loop to check the numbers entered by user are valid and outputs them
# to a file called numbers.txt
# The loop will only let you enter numbers from 1000 to 9999
x=0
until [ ! $x -ne $br2update ]
do
  echo "Enter number"
  read store
     if [ $store -gt 1000 ] && [ $store -lt 9999 ]
        then
            echo $store >> numbers.txt
            x=`echo "$x + 1" | bc`
     else
         echo "Invalid number"
         
fi

Comment: that's a very different question and should be posted separately.

Answer (score 2):

‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

```
paste -sd' ' file
```